# Unbounded knapsack/coin change with optimal solution for non-standard coins

Tags: dynamic, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, coin-change

I have the following problem:

> Given a target size N and some denominations of some randomly
>   generated coins stored in array denominations[] check using dynamic
>   programming if there is an optimal solution which will fill the entire
>   target with the least amount of coins used.

This is a typical example of coin change problem, however unlike real life currency where each denomination is carefully picked so that any target can be matched this is not the case.

I am familiar with the algorithm used in coin change problem and how to construct a dynamic programming array to find the solution but how do I check if there is a solution in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the state be denoted by `DP[i][sum]` :the minimum number of coins used to form sum using starting i coins of the array denominations .
Then the recurrence can be formulated as:

```
DP[i][sum]= min(DP[i-1][sum],DP[i][sum-denominations[i]]+1)
```

Why??
The first `DP[i-1][sum]` denotes the number of coins needed to form sum using i-1 coins only (the case in which we exclude the i th denomination), The other case when we include the i th coin (Note : I have assumed we can include tthe coin multiple times that is why I wrote `DP[i][sum-denominations[i]].`

Now, The base cases, `DP[i][0]=0` i.e. the NULL set(for all i belonging from 0 to n(the number of denominations)! and `DP[0][i]=+INFINITY` where 1<=i<=sum .

Now when the DP table is filled up, You can easily check whether DP[n(the size)][sum] is not equal to +INFINITY then there exists a solution else wise not..

If you know how to construct a solution (as you said) , You can construct the solution for this solution too..

P.S. : For allowing only single time inclusion of a coin denomination the recurrence changes to

```
DP[i][sum]= min(DP[i-1][sum],DP[i-1][sum-denominations[i]]+1)
```

by the same logic! I think base cases will be same!

Comment: I suppose when you say DP[i][sum] you mean DP[i][j] and j is ranging from 0 to sum right?

Comment: Yes .. Where j is a smaller sum than the real actual SUM ..   Just playing with variables and nothing else

Comment: You can change sum to j .... Where j varies from 1 to actual SUM or in my notations sum varies from 1 to SUM (actual) ..